# Combining three queries

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.6

I am having the table structure

```
id |  name  |   desig    |  age
1  |   John | supervisor |   M/28
2  | Deborah | Manager   |  F/44
3  | Joan   |Area Manager|  M/52
```

I am trying to get the count of employees by their `desig` grouped by age .
Here is the query that is working

```
SELECT sum(case when desig='Manager' then 1 else 0 end ) AS Manager
     , sum(case when desig='Area Manager' then 1 else 0 end ) AS Amanager
     , sum(case when desig='Superwisor' then 1 else 0 end ) AS SW
FROM employee_details 
WHERE substring_index(age,'/',-1) < 30
```

So that i can get the count of employees grouped by designation below 30. I need to get similar counts for the age group between 30-40 , 40-50 and above 50 . Should i go for four different `SELECT`  queries or is there a different ,more performant way to do this .

Comment: Using COUNT instead of SUM will make it a bit shorter (and more intuitive IMOH): `COUNT(case when desig='Manager' then 1 end )`. I also agree with @Kondybas, don't store age and gender in the same column. In fact don't store age at all, use birth_date and determine the age at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a few more rows just to check it.

```
create table employee_details (id int, name text, desig text, age text);

insert into employee_details values
(1, 'John',    'Supervisor',   'M/28'),
(2, 'Deborah', 'Manager',      'F/44'),
(3, 'Joan',    'Area Manager', 'M/52'),
(4, 'Anna',    'Manager',      'F/35'),
(5, 'Rose',    'Area Manager', 'M/55');
```

Age group can be computed in this way:

```
(substring_index(age, '/', -1) DIV 10) * 10 as age_group
```

Then you can GROUP BY `desig` and `age group`:

```
SELECT   desig,
         (substring_index(age, '/', -1) DIV 10) * 10 as age_group,
         count(*) as count_emp
FROM     employee_details
GROUP BY (substring_index(age, '/', -1) DIV 10) * 10, desig
ORDER BY (substring_index(age, '/', -1) DIV 10) * 10, desig;
```

> ```
> desig        | age_group | count_emp
> :----------- | --------: | --------:
> Supervisor   |        20 |         1
> Manager      |        30 |         1
> Manager      |        40 |         1
> Area Manager |        50 |         2
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=12a5c0b37de9c243ce183f3d2b06543c)*</kbd>

For a custom age groups I'd suggest a tally table:

```
create table age_group (id int, name text, low int, high int);

insert into age_group values
(1, '< 25',   0,  25),
(2, '25-35', 25,  35),
(3, '35-40', 35,  40),
(4, '40-50', 40,  50),
(5, '>= 50', 50, 150);
```

Then you can CROSS JOIN this table with all possible designations and use an scalar subquery to get count of employees.

```
SELECT ed.desig,
       ag.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   employee_details
        WHERE  substring_index(age, '/', -1) >= ag.low
        AND    substring_index(age, '/', -1) < ag.high
        AND    desig = ed.desig) count_emp
FROM   age_group ag
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT desig 
            FROM   employee_details) ed;
```

> ```
> desig        | name  | count_emp
> :----------- | :---- | --------:
> Supervisor   | < 25  |         0
> Supervisor   | 25-35 |         1
> Supervisor   | 35-40 |         0
> Supervisor   | 40-50 |         0
> Supervisor   | >= 50 |         0
> Manager      | < 25  |         0
> Manager      | 25-35 |         0
> Manager      | 35-40 |         1
> Manager      | 40-50 |         1
> Manager      | >= 50 |         0
> Area Manager | < 25  |         0
> Area Manager | 25-35 |         0
> Area Manager | 35-40 |         0
> Area Manager | 40-50 |         0
> Area Manager | >= 50 |         2
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8596e72ade9aa47c5e109f496827dae8)*</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the solution , is there any way i can alter it for using for different age group , say for  < 25 , 25-35  .. so on , other than using `CASE WHEN THEN ` .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with integer division operation that way:

```
SELECT count(*), w.age DIV 10 AS age_tens
  FROM table AS w
 GROUP BY w.age DIV 10
```

But I'm strongly recommend to revise way you store gender/age and position.

Comment: I was trying to make all the age group `SELECT` query to a single one  ..... think it is almost impossible . Regarding the db structure i will try to convince the maintainers about changing Gender and Age to separate Columns .